# Aligning elements horizontally adjacent that are in different grid cells with CSS Grid and Flexbox

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox, css-grid

Currently I'm using a mixture between grid and flexbox to try and achieve a layout for a form.

I would like both `input` elements to horizontally lineup without setting a height on them. If I were to apply for padding on the text input, the range should continue to vertically center with the input adjacent to it.

Additionally I would like the `label` elements to also remain horizontally aligned too.

Please suggest solutions that **DO NOT** require changing the markup or using Javascript.

**Currently what I have:**
[image]

**What I'm trying to achieve:**
[image]

I know I could apply a fixed height or padding on the range to align it but I'm trying to make this as fluid as possible.

**HTML:**

```
<form class="grid">
  <div class="group">
    <label for="input-1">Label 1</label>
    <input type="text" id="input-1" placeholder="placeholder" />
  </div>

  <div class="group">
    <label for="input-2">Label 2</label>
    <div class=range-wrapper>
      <input type="range" id="input-2" placeholder="placeholder" />
      <output>0</output>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

**SCSS:**

```
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.grid {
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 960px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 40px 10px;

  padding: 50px;
  background: #ccc;
}

.group {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-top: auto;

  label {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
}

input {
  font-size: inherit;

  &[type="text"] {
    padding: 14px;
  }
  &[type="range"] {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.range-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;

  output {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

You can also check out the [codepen here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QVvVRR).

Many thanks!

---

** **EDIT** **

Should support multiline labels, if the label wraps multiple lines, elements should still horizontally align.

Multiline label example: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zJwXYQ)

Comment: There is no CSS property or layout methid that allows for alignment of elements **that do not share a parent**.

Comment: What you can do is force the last item in the group div all the way to the bottom of the row...something like this - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/GXmVWv

Comment: This works the same as just adding `margin-bottom: auto` to the `label` element. Plus if I wanted to put more `input` groups into the grid it wouldn't work. Also, this doesn't actually fixed the align issue between the `input` and `range` adjacently.

Comment: As I said....there is **NO** CSS method for that.

Answer (score 1):

try this for your "group" class.
(or use a new class for that element with this styling)

```
.group {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;

  label {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
}
```

Comment: I originally tried this, but the problem with this is now the `label` elements do not lineup with each other...

Comment: how about you add a `flex: 1` to `range-wrapper` class and remove the `margin-bottom` from `Label 2`

Comment: What happens if it's a multiline label, example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zJwXYQ

Comment: I think it would be easier to give the input and `range-wrapper` a specific height, and add `justify-content: center` to `group` class.
here is the codepen: [link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QVvVRR)

Comment: Did you forget to fork your changes? I'm really against the fixed height positioning for multiple reasons. For example, if I decided to change the root font-size, this could cause breakages in the layout.

Comment: sorry, i guess i copied the wrong one
here is the correct one: [codepen](https://codepen.io/KimiaBashiran/pen/YOVMNN)

Comment: No worries, but once again I did try with a fixed height while looking through various solutions before coming to Stack Overflow, The fixed height is something I would really like to avoid.

Comment: could you please send an example one of the situation where fixed height cause problem?

Comment: Here an example with a fixed `height` on the `range-wrapper` and changing the `:root` `font-size`: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QVgGgL

Comment: both `range-wrapper` and the `input` need to have fixed height, I just added a fixed height to input in your example and it's working fine: https://codepen.io/KimiaBashiran/pen/KxqEPM

Comment: I mean, technically you can just add the height to the `input` and it will apply for the range too. I was hoping to find another solution that didn't require the fixed height though... If I decided to choose a different font-size, or padding size, or font-family, the height could cause issues, hence why I want it to be as fluid as possible.

Comment: I think other than fixed height you can try change the structure. That means labels having a same parent, input and `ranger-wrapper` with one parent, and the children having a 50% width (or `flex:1`). (i didn't add margin or padding to left or right)
[example](https://codepen.io/KimiaBashiran/pen/KxqEPM)